# Select variables that don't exist in another table

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to do a php sql query where I get objects whose user_id aren't in another database table. Here's my query now:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE user_id='$show_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Inside it, I check if it's in my other table. It will only echo if it does not exist in the table. The problem is, is that it won't display it's full 10 in the limit.

So my thoughts would be to create one sql query that counts to see if it exists in the other database table.

In my past I have only done simple sql queries (as shown above) and not many multi-table ones as well as putting a query inside a query. Please help!

Comment: Sounds like a great place to RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: People will be more able to provide specific examples if you provide table schemas in your question.

Comment: Sorry for not being so specific in my question. Digging through and simplifying my code would be difficult! I did, however, get many answers that helped me tremendously! Thanks to everyone's input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `NOT EXISTS` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 AS t
WHERE user_id='$show_id' 
  AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM OtherTable AS ot
        WHERE ot.user_id = t.user_id
      )
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one query:

```
SELECT *
FROM first_table
WHERE user_id NOT IN (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM second_table
)
```

This will get all records from `first_table` where `user_id` does not occur in the `user_id` column of `second_table`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
  FROM   table1 t1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 on t2.user_id = t1.user_id
 WHERE   t1.user_id = '$show_id'
   AND   t2.user_id IS NULL
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: NOT EXISTS is way more intuitive for sql beginners than join clauses and null checking.

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN is an elegant way! Its better to learn the better way, if you are a beginner :)

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` are far more simple and easy to understand. Elegance is closer to simplicity. And sometimes `NOT EXISTS` performs fatser than `LEFT JOIN + IS NULL`

Comment: Sometimes Left Outer Join performs faster. It all depends on your coding methodology. we'll, let me put it this way ... my answer uses Left Outer Join. The person asking the question may or may not choose to accept my answer.

Comment: [not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) and [left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but it sounds like you are looking for the `NOT EXISTS` subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select id from othertable where id = user_id) AND user_id='$show_id'
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```